# Splitting a string in a file into array in c

Tags: c, string, file, strtok, split

I'm new to programming,and I have a small problem.
I have a file named `questions.txt` containing a string of questions, I want to read the string from the file then split it into array with each question having an index, for example `a[i] = "Question i"` etc.
I did so many tries, but it always ends up reading the last line in the file, when write a loop the program stops working.

This is what i came up with, it's all probably wrong:

```
char str[200];

char *ptr;
FILE * fp = fopen("questions.txt", "r");
while(fgets(str, 200, fp)!= NULL)
printf("%s", str);
ptr = strtok(str, "\n");

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    ptr = strtok(str, "\n");
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
fclose(fp);
```

The file is:

```
what is your course?
who is your instructor?
```

Output i get is:

```
what is your course?
who is your instructor?
who is your instructor?
```

Comment: Add your code in your question, it will be a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The people here are very willing to help solve specific problems with code, but they don't give you the full answers.  Please read [ask], where among other things, they tell you to put some of the code you have tried and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to read the string from the file then split it into an array with each question having an index...

Let me say, that you don't have a string to split into array.
You should better have a file with a one string of questions like this:

```
what is your course?:who is your instructor?  // `:` is some kind of delimiter
```

I can suppose that you want to make a vector (one dimensional array) of the file. And in that vector, each element will contain a question from the file. Right?

I can share with you a function from my library I've made at the university. I'll write here a simple program. But it uses ***delimiters*** - `:`, for example. You can modify this function for working without delimiters --  this only depends on you.

In two words, this little program does the following:

```
// BEFORE: you have a string that ends with a null terminating character.
Question_1_abcbadsad:QUestion_2asasdasd:Question_3sldasdsa\n
                                                          ^
                                                     here ^<< printing 'string' stops
// AFTER: an array of questions. Each of them ends with a null terminating character.
Question_1_abcbadsad\nQUestion_2asasdasd\nQuestion_3sldasdsa\n
                    ^
                    ^<< printing argz[0] will stop here
```

**main.c**

```
#include "argz.h"

int main()
{
    error_t func;     

    char *argz; // pointer to a vector; to an array of questions

    size_t argz_len;  
    // size of that vector (the size of the string you've got from the file)
    // Consider `string` to be your `ptr`. You read a string from the file so
    // `ptr` will point to the string.         

    char *string = "Question_1_abcbadsad:QUestion_2asasdasd:Question_3sldasdsa";

    // Here `:` is a separate character.
    func = argz_create_sep(string, ':', &argz, &argz_len);
    if(func == OK)
        argz_print(argz, argz_len);
    else
        printf("ERROR\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**argz.c**

```
#include "argz.h"

error_t argz_create_sep (const char *string, int sep, char **argz, size_t *argz_len)
{
    int i;
    char *ch;
    int len = strlen(string);

    if(len==0)
        return ENOMEM;

    *argz = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(len + 1));
    strcpy(*argz, string);
    *argz_len = strlen(*argz);
    ch = *argz;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(*ch == sep) *ch='\0';
        ch++;
    }
    return OK;
}


void argz_print(const char *argz, size_t argz_len)
{
    const char *ch;
    int i;

    ch = argz;
    for(i = 0; i < argz_len; i++) {
        if(*ch == '\0')
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf("%c",*ch);
        ch++;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

**argz.h**

```
#include <stddef.h> // for size_t
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum  {OK, ENOMEM} error_t;

/* function prototypes */
error_t  argz_create_sep (const char *string, int sep, char **argz, size_t *argz_len);
void     argz_print      (const char *argz, size_t argz_len);
```

Comment: @z.n14, I recommend you to use the function I posted here. It is very useful and you'll be able to apply it in all your next programs. I use this function almost every time when I have to deal with text and files. I strongly recommend to use it in your program -- you'll see, it will be breathtakingly.

Comment: The code presented here seems to use functions that are part of the GNU C library [argz functions](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Argz-Functions.html#Argz-Functions) - claiming: "*...I can share with you a function from my library I've made at the university...*" seems a bit off to me... 8-(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i=0;
char str[200],s='1'; //s is give a random character  

FILE * fp = fopen("questions.txt", "r");
while (s!=EOF){     //works until s= the end of file
    s=getc(fp);          //s starts to receive characters from text file
    str[i]=s;   //each character of text is placed into the string array
    i++;        
}
str[i]='\0'; //s reached EOF so lets indicate where we stopped in the string
fclose(fp);

printf("%s\n",str);

//EDIT: changing 1D str to 2D str2 
char str2[10][200]; // 10 for max no. of questions, 200 - length of each question
int j=0,k=0;
i=0;

for(j=0;j<200;j++){  
str2[i][k]=str[j];
k++;
    if (str[j]=='\n'){
    i++;
    k=0;}
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++)  //prints your 2D string array
printf("%s",str2[i]); //after the last question there will be junk
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but doesnt this only store characters in index "i"? I'm trying to get a whole question in 1 index

Comment: do you know the difference between say str[10] and str[10][100] ?

Comment: first one is a one dimensional array, points to the 10th element
and second is 2 dimensional array points to the element in column 10 row 100, right?

Comment: if char a[10] = "hello" this means a[0]='h', a[1]='e', a[2]='l' ..etc *every element is one character long.

Comment: I wanted something like a[1] = "question x"
is that possible?

Comment: it can only work like: a[1][j] = "question x" (for j=0 to 200)